Poisson-Equation for radial symmetric point charge
Poissons Eq. for radial symmetric systems is
$$ \Delta\psi = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} \left(r^2 \frac{d\psi}{dr} \right) =   -\frac{\rho(r)}{\varepsilon_0} $$
Imagine a point charge $q$ located at $r=0$, the coulomb potential is
$$ \psi(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}$$
The derivatives are
$$ \frac{d\psi}{dr} = -\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}$$
$$ \frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2} = \frac{q}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3}$$
If I insert this into the Poisson Eq. using $\Delta\psi = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} \left(r^2 \frac{d\psi}{dr} \right)= \frac{1}{r} \left(2 \frac{d\psi}{dr} + r \frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2} \right) = -\frac{\rho(r)}{\varepsilon_0}$ I get
$$ - \frac{\rho(r)}{\varepsilon_0}=\frac{1}{r} \left(-\frac{2q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2} + r\frac{q}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3} \right) = 0 $$
But the charge density should not be zero everywhere right? Is dividing by zero the reason? But for me it doesn't make sense, as the above eqation may be written as
$$ - \frac{\rho(r)}{\varepsilon_0}=-\frac{q}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3} + \frac{q}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3} = 0 $$
and two equivalent terms should always cancel out right?

Remember that $\Delta \frac{1}{r}=-4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x})$.

This is a classical application of $\delta (\textbf{r})$ function.
Actually, the charge density distribution in the whole space should be $q\delta (\textbf{r-r}_{0})$ instead of $0$ everywhere.
If you don't know about $\delta$ function, I recommend you learn something about its basic properties, for it is really a widely-used function in physics.
Then when did the $\delta$ function come out? Actually, you've already discovered something wrong:

Is dividing by zero the reason?

The answer is YES. when r $\neq$ 0, all the calculations are correct. However, if r=0, we'll have to reconsider the formulas.
In fact, there is a useful formula writes:
$$\nabla ^{2} \frac{1}{r}=-4\pi\delta(\textbf{r})$$
if we plug this in, then we can easily bring up the delta function and have the correct charge density distribution in the space:
$$\rho(\textbf{r})=q\delta(\textbf{r})$$
